# SQL Query: Column Name as Value

Tags: union, redshift

I have a Redshift table that looks like the following:

```
+----------------+---------------+------+
| FieldA         | field1        |field2|
+----------------+---------------+------+
| ABC            | 123           |   78 |
| DEF            | 456           |   90 |
+----------------+---------------+------+
```

I want to run a query to produce the following output. I believe I have to use a

UNION ALL

to get the fields I want split up into different rows, but I'm not sure how to get the column names (field1, field2) as values within a column.

```
+----------------+---------------+------+
| FieldA         | value         |field |
+----------------+---------------+------+
| ABC            | 123           |field1|
| DEF            | 456           |field1|
| ABC            | 78            |field2|
| DEF            | 90            |field2|
+----------------+---------------+------+
```

(I don't care about output order at the moment)

Comment: If your RDBMS supports `UNPIVOT`, use `UNPIVOT`

Answer (score 1):

You are right about `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. Due to the field column, the legs in the UNION will be disjoint:

```
SELECT FieldA, field1 as value, 'field1' as field
FROM T
UNION ALL
SELECT FieldA, field2 as value, 'field2' as field
FROM T
```

I don't think MySQL as of latest version yet supports `LATERAL`, but I may be mistaken so in case it does, it will be slightly more efficient to do something like:

```
SELECT x.FieldA, x.value, x.field
FROM T
LATERAL JOIN (
    values (T.FieldA, field1, 'field1')
         , (T.FieldA, field2, 'field2')
) x (FieldA, value, field);
```

You may have to do:

```
LATERAL JOIN (
    SELECT T.FieldA, field1 as value, 'field1' as field
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.FieldA, field2 as value, 'field2' as field
) x;
```

Comment: The question tags have been edited. They use Redshift (a product based on postgres), not MySQL. I don't think it supports `LATERAL` but not sure.